WiFi network random error with Ubuntu 24.04
I have problems connecting to WiFi on a Thinkpad T16 Gen 2 AMD with a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04
The strange thing is that after a few reboots the pc works fine. But sometimes when I start it says activation of network connection failed.
I have this warning:
service NetworkManager status

Nov 17 15:55:50 andres-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-2 NetworkManager[980]: <info>  [1731869750.2152] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Nov 17 15:55:50 andres-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-2 NetworkManager[980]: <info>  [1731869750.2152] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Nov 17 15:55:50 andres-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-2 NetworkManager[980]: <info>  [1731869750.2152] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Nov 17 15:55:50 andres-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-2 NetworkManager[980]: <info>  [1731869750.2440] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Nov 17 15:56:15 andres-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-2 NetworkManager[980]: <warn>  [1731869775.6887] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Nov 17 15:56:15 andres-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-2 NetworkManager[980]: <info>  [1731869775.6888] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'ma>
Nov 17 15:56:15 andres-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-2 NetworkManager[980]: <info>  [1731869775.6891] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Nov 17 15:56:15 andres-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-2 NetworkManager[980]: <warn>  [1731869775.6892] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'CabanasOasis1'
Nov 17 15:56:15 andres-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-2 NetworkManager[980]: <info>  [1731869775.6893] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'manage>
Nov 17 15:56:15 andres-ThinkPad-T16-Gen-2 NetworkManager[980]: <info>  [1731869775.7108] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected


lspci -k

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc QCNFA765 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCNFA765 Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: ath11k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath11k_pci

I tried updating the kernel, but nothing solves the problem. I tried installing Ubuntu 22.04, but I can't even connect on the installer.
The machine came with Windows 11, and that seems to work all right.
Any idea if I can try a few things before contact Lenovo support?
EDIT:
iwconfig (currently working):
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0f0  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"CabanasOasis1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: 68:72:51:54:57:E9   
          Bit Rate=104 Mb/s   Tx-Power=13 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

iwconfig (not working):

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0f0  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off



What is the output of iwconfig Please edit your question and add that information.

In terminal sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off  See if it bahves
